# Difficult in making a separate LAYOUT in GWT java app

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

i am looking forward to make a welcome screen of my web app like the picture i shown..

here is a pic of example:

http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/4144/1j5h.png

The truth is i have tested many almost all the panels that GWT has to offer, and still i cannot make it.

For example:

The upper header, i made it with a DockLayoutPanel like this:

```
DockLayoutPanel Header = new DockLayoutPanel(unit.PCT);
header.setStyleName(¨fw¨);

header.setWidht("100%");

header.setHeight("35px");
header.addEast(ingresar,15);
header.addEast(pass,15);
header.addEast(user,15);
```

Using that panel, i can have all the 2 boxes and the button on the right corner of the screen, and with AUTO-WITDH.

*(even i cannot pad the red button)..

As you can check the horizontal Center Panel has a different style, i create it as Horizontal Panel, but when i do :

header.add(center_panel);
It is useless, the css from header will ofuscate the css from horizontal panel, also i cannot get the box right in the CENTER.

i have zero experience in GWT, i would like if someone can tell me the way, because i am using panels and i am not quite sure that i am using the right ones for this tasks, or the best ones.

THanks very much
Facundo

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have much experience in GWT components try creating the UI with using GWT UI Binder. Its much more similar to creating a layout with html and css. Also you can use most of the html elements such as divs,spans etc.. [GWT Uibinder](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder)

Answer (score 0):

You can give styles on individual panels like,
for horizontal,

HorizontalPanel hp=new HorizontalPanel();

hp.setStyleName("");